# CSS move Icon to right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I created a UI with a Icon, User Name and Phone number below. The CSS properties I used for Image are

```
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-left: 4%;
```

[image]

When i  increase margin-left the image and usrname both are moving to right side. I just want to move the icon to right a little bit. How Can Do That ?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML markup and what selector you're using with your posted CSS?

Comment: With `position:relative`, use `left:XXpx` instead of `margin-left`

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle for your code so that we can edit it and help you

Comment: Padding-left can work, depending on your code and etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to give you a specific answer without the exact Markup and the context in which you're writing your CSS.  However, I would suggest following the Markup and Styles that are written in most newer CSS Frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) and [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/).  They both use span or i elements to attach the icons to, so your HTML is semantically valid.  Also, this will give you more flexibility to apply your specific icons styles.

Inspecting the i element in the Font Awesome example should give you a good idea of some base icon styles and should allow you to get the desired look.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `position: relative;` for your icon, just use `left: 4%` (or whatever value) instead of `margin-left`, which moves the relatively positioned element in relation to its original position without affecting anything else around it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to the wrapping element and `position:absolute` to the icon. Then, add `right:4%` to the icon, and adjust the value to get the margin you want.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) is some info on what CSS positioning is.

I'll quote the part which explains this solution:

> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.
> Note: Absolute positioned elements are removed from the normal flow, and can overlap elements.